# "One home run is much better than two doubles"

Tags: quotes

It is a quote said by Steve Jobs. I have found a lot about it in www.sqaforums.com. But I don't get it clearly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *home run* in baseball terminology means a hit that goes out of the park, or cannot be fielded in time, thereby scoring the batter at least one run.

In baseball there are four bases. That is the number of bases covered in a home run. In other words, all of them.

In a double, the batter only reaches second base. Two doubles can be tallied with no runs scored, given the circumstances (see "for the record" at the end of this answer). In other words, two plus two doesn't always equal four, at least in baseball.

So the guaranteed score of the home run (one run guaranteed, or more if there are men on base) may be seen as better than the not-necessarily-scoring two doubles.

Suffice it to say that what Jobs meant was that a guaranteed run is better than something that adds up to the same total of bases but doesn't put a run on the scoreboard.

**For the record**: No analogy is accurate to six decimal places. There are cases where two doubles *are* preferable to a single home run. For one thing, pitchers pitch differently with men on base. And so on. The point is not that we can't point up trivial loopholes in the analogy, but that Steve Jobs was making the point that he would rather make one big splash than a couple of little splashes. Home runs put asses in seats in a ball park, and Apple achieved their phenomenal success by always concentrating on showmanship and The Next Big Thing, not The Next Couple of Little Things.

Comment: Yeah. Some what I understand. Problem is, I don't know baseball. Shall I take it as, In cricket six and singles.

Comment: I would be hesitant to compare baseball to cricket. For all their similarities, they are vastly different sports. Suffice it to say that what Jobs meant was that a guaranteed run is better than something that adds up to the same total of bases but doesn't put a run on the scoreboard.

Comment: Or, more broadly, he meant that it's better to concentrate one's resources on making a single great work than it is to create two works of half the merit.

Comment: It's also not entirely accurate. If you're in the same inning, 2 doubles gives you a run, likely clears the bases, and leaves you with someone on 2nd.

Comment: @jimm101: As I said, "given the circumstances" ... it is not necessary to detail all the baseball rules and situations to answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Robusto Yup...not disagreeing with you, just Steve.

Comment: Well, I remember a game years ago where, after only two pitches had been thrown in the game, two batters each hit a double. So one run scored and there was a runner on second, who therefore had a very good chance of scoring a second run before the end of the inning. The team was clearly doing better than if the first batter had hit a home run and the second batter was about to come up.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Please read my addendum.

Comment: @Robusto : I wasn't actually contradicting your main point.

Comment: As a baseball fan, I would take it as "A baseball player who hits a home run in one game is a much better hitter than those who hit two doubles in one game".  I agree "Steve Jobs was making the point that he would rather make a big splash than a couple of little splashes."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Steve Jobs favored "a home run" over "two doubles" because in baseball a home run constitutes a sure way to produce a run and is therefore superior to two two-base hits (which can, under certain circumstances, fail to yield a run).

Rather, I think he used "home run" in its business sense of referring to something that is an "out-of-the-park hit"—that is, a massive success. I encountered this business sense of the term a few years ago when editing an end-of-year summary to investors by a venture capitalist. In reviewing the results of his firm's investments over the previous year, he divided the results into three categories: hits, misses, and home runs. These roughly corresponded to moderately successful investments, unproductive or failed investments, and tremendous successes.

The website [Office Slang](http://www.officeslang.com/) offers this entry for the term:

> **Home run** A big financial win. Example: The investor passed on the deal because he did not think it could be a home run.

In baseball, a solo home run doesn't produce any more value than a run scored on a walk, two stolen bases, and a throw by the catcher that sails down the left-field line for an error. And as jimm101 notes in a comment beneath Robusto's answer (which I don't mean to disparage), there are many situations in a real baseball game where two doubles are preferable to a single home run, because more often than not the two doubles yield a run scored plus a runner on second base.

My point is that it's inaccurate to take a baseball home run's guaranteed one-run value literally as the value Jobs attributes to what he is calling a "home run." He means that a huge runaway commercial success is better than two solid but unspectacular commercial successes. In adopting the business-jargon sense of "home run," his comment is valid—but its validity is far more dubious when applied nonfiguratively to the game of baseball.

Comment: Of course Jobs was using the term metaphorically. So is business. But you can't ignore the source of the metaphor. This is amplified by the fact that he didn't just say "home run" but added "two doubles": clearly he was thinking more strictly in terms of baseball than you seem to be willing to allow. He did not sever the tie to the source, but bound it more tightly.

Comment: @Robusto: I guess my position is that "home run" as a slang term in business has its own existence and therefore its own integrity, but that to the extent that it purports to reflect accurately the magnitude of a home run in baseball it is (so to speak) way off base. And to the extent that Jobs reinforces the business slang expression's allusion to real baseball, he compounds its inaccuracy as a representation of the true proportionate significance of a home run in the actual game. Of course, he could be referring to doubles that occur in separate innings or even separate ball games...

Comment: ...By the way, I strongly agree with your supplementary remark about the value of home runs in drawing crowds. From an owner's perspective, winning is nice but having a full house every night is even better.  And from a ball player's perspective, a home run may well be worth more than two doubles. One of the two most famous comments about hitting (along with "No one walks his way off the [Caribbean] island") is the one to the effect that "The big money is in the big flies." That leaves only the manager to prefer the option that is likelier to win more games over the course of a season.

Comment: ...Actually "Hit 'em where they ain't" is more famous than either of those two comments—but Wee Willie Keeler was a singles hitter.

Comment: They all were in the dead-ball era. The way they held the bat was even different, with the hands several inches apart on the handle.Not conducive to home-run hitting, to be sure.